# How to write a python script to execute a .blend file and modify it

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I am doing a complicated 3D scene model. Actually, I am using the blender GUI (not python script) to do it. Once I designed the scene, I need to move randomly an object in the scene for many times. So, I am wondering, if possible to write a python script that execute the *.blend file and then in the same script, I write lines to move randomly the object. Any suggestion?

Comment: do you mean "Open" by "execute" , is your workflow like this  : 1-Open the blend file of the scene  2-move the object 3-do something 3-close without saving , and repeat

Comment: @Chebhou, I need to write a script xxx.py that include kind of execute or import of .blend file and below that a loop to move an object randomly in the scene and for example after each iteration i can save a mesh as *.stl file.

Comment: so you have the scene blend file open, then import the object from another blend file , move the object and export each time

Answer (score -1):

```
import bpy 
from random import randint 

# Generate 50 cubes in random locations for i in range(50):
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = [ randint( -10, 10 ) for axis in 'xyz' ])
```

Replace cube with your model and this should work.